# OS X 10.6.x: How to use launchd to start a script at specific system events (startup, login, logout, shutdown)?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, login, shutdown, launchd, logout

We've tried to create scripts that run at startup, login, logout and shutdown. We had them up and running with 10.4 but can't get it running with 10.6
What is the right way to use launchd/launchctl to run a script only at login, logout startup, or shutdown on `OS X 10.6`?

Comment: Are you asking for all 4, or only for logout and shut down?

Comment: We need all four events but to differ between logout and shutdown are most essential for us.